# Error WPF Cannot locate resource using TeamFoundation 10.0 and Visual Studio 2012 in Windows8

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, tfs, team-explorer

I use VS 2012 (with Update 4) in Windows 8. I have installed my Addin for VS.

When I open VS 2012 I get the following error ***Cannot locate resource 'teamexplorer/homepageview.xaml'***

Another partner in my company hasn't any problem. He has VS 2012 (update 4), and Windows 8 too. He install the Addin, and it works right.

The Addin uses TeamFoundation libraries version 10.0.

Any suggestions about it?

**UPDATE:**

If I copy and replace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.*.dll and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.dll (from 10.0 version to 11.0 version) in my C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MyAddins, and change devenv.exe.config for do assembly redirect (10.0 to 11.0 version)  the error doesn't appears.

But I get new error for my Addin: Could not load assembly file  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Cliente.dll version 10.0.0.0

> If I use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.*.dll version **10.0.0.0**, TeamExplorer
>   fails
>
> If I use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.*.dll version **11.0.0.0**, my Addin
>   fails

Anyaways, in another PC with Windows 8 and VS 2012 Update 4, my Addin works right using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.*.dll version 10.0.0.0.

Any suggestions?

Full error:

> System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource
>   'teamexplorer/homepageview.xaml'.    at
>   MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access)    at
>   System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access)    at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream()    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.HomePageView.InitializeComponent()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.HomePage.CreateView(PageInitializeEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerPageBase.Initialize(Object
>   sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.TeamExplorerAsyncPageBase.Initialize(Object
>   sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerPageHost.Initialize(TeamExplorerPageContext
>   context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Addin will have to make use of a [`bindingRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) to redirect all versions to from v10 to v11.

View more in this answer:
[Error TF249051 using TFS 2008, VS 2012 and Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374438/error-tf249051-using-tfs-2008-vs-2012-and-windows-8/22545074#22545074)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you had the same problem as me. But in my case I used 2 assemblies. The first containing the addin code to manage my menus throught Visual Studio. The second managing few code like code generators and dialogs. This last one was containing my WPF dialogs. When i tried to show any dialogue with my addin, I got exactly the same error as you.

After many tries, i added the System.Xaml reference to my addin assembly and that's worked. I had just forgotten to add the reference to the addin ...