# Error TF249051 using TFS 2008, VS 2012 and Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, tfs

I have a Addin for Visual Studio, that connect to TFS 2008 server. I use VS 2012 in Windows 7 and Windows 8 (and 8.1).

No problem using my Addin, VS 2012 and Windows 7. All is OK.

But there is authentication issue using My Addin, VS 2012 and Windows 8.
Anyway, if I use Team Explorer and Source Control in VS 2012, there's no problem.

I get the following error:

> TF249051: No URL can be found that corresponds to the following server
>   name: myTFS_server. Verify that the server name is correct.

Full trace:

```
Trace DomainName: myTFS_server
Trace DomainUri: http://myTFS_server:8080/
Trace  ProjectName: MyTeamProject
Trace  ProjectUri: vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/5e1c44c0-a88c-4447-b2d3-1e9191abc700
Source Control: System.__ComObject

Error in Connect to TFS: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationInvalidServerNameException: TF249051: No URL can be found that corresponds to the following server name: myTFS_server. Verify that the server name is correct.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName(String name, String locationServiceRelativePath, Func`2 getRegisteredUri)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName(String name)
   at TeamExplorerManager.TFSServer.Connect(String serverName, ICredentialsProvider credentialsProvider)

TF249051: No URL can be found that corresponds to the following server name: myTFS_server. Verify that the server name is correct.. SourceControl: http://myTFS_server:8080/vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/5e1c44c0-a88c-4447-b2d3-1e9191abc700.
Targets {http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}Project
*** End OnStartupComplete ***
```

Any suggestions about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Addin will have to make use of a [`bindingRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) to redirect all versions to from v10 to v11.

For example:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation"
                              publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0"
                             newVersion="11.0.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>

         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client"
                              publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0"
                             newVersion="11.0.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Make sure to update the `publicKeyToken` to the correct value.

Note:
Specific version [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417481/can-you-ignore-specific-versions-of-strongly-named-references) if the assembly is [strong name signed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4fa028b.aspx).

Microsoft almost certainly strong-name signed their assembly.

References:
[SpecificVersion=False with TFS API dll's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801219/specificversion-false-with-tfs-api-dlls)